# Conditional creation of a Dataframe column - ValueError

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, valueerror

So, I'm running this code to add a new column based on conditions from other columns.

```
conditions = [
    (df['PMA'] == 'EEA') & (75 > df['AR'] >= 55) & (70 > df['RR'] >= 55) & (df['SR'] <= 75) & (df['RMA'] <= 130),
    (df['PMA'] == 'EEA') & (df['AR'] >= 75) & (df['RR'] >= 70) & (df['SR'] <= 75) & (df['RMA'] <= 130),
    (df['PMA'] == 'EMERGING') & (70 > df['AR'] >= 50) & (60 > df['RR'] >= 50) & (df['SR'] <= 75) & (df['RMA'] <= 130),
    (df['PMA'] == 'EMERGING') & (df['AR'] >= 70) & (df['RR'] >= 60) & (df['SR'] <= 75) & (df['RMA'] <= 130)
]
choices = ['PSS Eligible', 'SSDI Eligible', 'PSS Eligible', 'SSDI Eligible']
df['Eligibility'] = np.select(conditions, choices, default='Not Eligible')
```

I'm getting the:

`ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().`

Any idea where does it come from?

EDIT:

According to your suggestions, I changed it to:

```
conditions = [
    (df['PMA'] == 'EEA') & (df['AR'] < 75) & (df['AR'] >= 55) & (df['RR'] < 70) & (df['RR'] >= 55) & (df['SR'] <= 75) & (df['RMA'] <= 130),
    (df['PMA'] == 'EEA') & (df['AR'] >= 75) & (df['RR'] >= 70) & (df['SR'] <= 75) & (df['RMA'] <= 130),
    (df['PMA'] == 'EMERGING') & (df['AR'] < 70) & (df['AR'] >= 50) & (df['RR'] < 60) & (df['RR'] >= 50) & (df['SR'] <= 75) & (df['RMA'] <= 130),
    (df['PMA'] == 'EMERGING') & (df['AR'] >= 70) & (df['RR'] >= 60) & (df['SR'] <= 75) & (df['RMA'] <= 130)
]
choices = ['PSS Eligible', 'SSDI Eligible', 'PSS Eligible', 'SSDI Eligible']
df['Eligibility'] = np.select(conditions, choices, default='Not Eligible')
```

It works now! Thank you!

Comment: `(75 > df['AR'] >= 55)` this does not work, use `(df['AR'] < 75) & df['AR'] >= 55)`

Comment: @Erfan hah we noticed at pretty much the same time ;)

Comment: Did you do any searching for the `where`?  Like testing each `(...)` expression to see which if any caused the problem?